# Mother's Milk significance

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

What was the significance of the mother's milk in [*Mad Max Fury Road (2015)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/)? It almost feels like there was a deleted scene that explains it.

Answer (score 4):

Human milk was one of the resources for trade and it most likely was meant for the elite:

> "They trade with one another for vital resources. In addition to
>   exporting water the Citadel also exports human milk, as earlier in the
>   film you see humans being milked. The milk is probably exclusive for
>   the elite of society as we only see Immortan Joe's son drinking it and
>   it's valuable enough to Gas Town to trade it for gas. As we don't see
>   any other mammals in the setting, the milk produced by the Citadel is
>   a pretty vital source of protein and nutrients in the wasteland."

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-war-rig-tanker-full-of-milk-and-what-is-it-for)

Comment: Immortal Joe was obsessed with having a healthy son (another thing that was glossed over in the movie); I feel the mother's milk has something to do with that. If it was just a resource it could have been left out of the movie entirely without affecting anything, so I feel there must be something more to it.

Comment: @ventsyv it could have been left out yes. But it goes that extra step to highlight just how difficult resources are to come by.

Comment: There's a deleted scene where a mother's baby is rejected as a future War Boy, but she gains admission to the upper levels of the Citadel because she's now able to produce mother's milk. The scene is not safe for work, and may be disturbing to some: https://youtu.be/thT-HbvpKYI